# Can't access attributes of select element javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't access the attributes of my select box via javascript.

My selector is, api is from the HP ski framework:

```
var t = api.lib.htmlTags
dp_group = t.select({id : "fm-new-flow_selectBox_dp_group"});
var selector = dp_group.$frag[0];
```

I can't use `document.getElementById("fm-new-flow_selectBox_dp_group")` because it says uncaught type error

if I use `console.log(selector)` the following is displayed

```
<select id="fm-new-flow_selectBox_dp_group">
    <option value="a" label="a" ofversion="1.100000023841858"></option>
    <option value="s" label="s" ofversion="1.100000023841858"></option>
</select>
```

If I call the options I get the following object (`console.log(selector.options)`):

```
[selectedIndex: -1]
0: option
1: option
length: 2
selectedIndex: 0
__proto__: HTMLOptionsCollection
```

But I can't select the single options with `selector.options[0]` (undefined). Also the length with `selector.length` or `selector.options.length` is 0.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `selector`?  Can you show a little more code - how you're getting hold of the element, exactly what your `console.log` statement looks like etc.

Comment: How do you set the `selector`variable? `document.getElementById("fm-new-flow_selectBox_dp_group").options.length` should return 2

Comment: This code [seems to be working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/4403bv29/), perhaps the issue lies elsewhere. Could you please add the code you use to select the `selector` variable.

Comment: use `document.getElementById('fm-new-flow_selectBox_dp_group')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `selector.options.item(0)` instead of `selector.options[0]`.

Your code does not work because `selector.options` is not a regualar array but an instance of `HTMLOptionsCollection`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection